# Mais de uma lista no mesmo loop

Tags: java, foreach, for

Posso colocar mais de uma lista no mesmo *loop*? por exemplo, dá para colocar mais de uma variável num `for`:

```
for (int a, b; a<10 b<20; a++ b++) {
   .......
}
```

Daí queria colocar mais de uma lista no mesmo `foreach`:

```
for(String s: lista) {

}
```

Comment: Creio que isso talvez nao seja possivel na segunda forma.

Comment: Cara acho que além de não ser possível, não é uma boa ideia. Por que você precisaria disso?

Comment: A ideia correta seria criar uma classe, estrutura ou objeto que tenha, objetos da duas listas, para você não fazer o relacionamento manualmente em todo for. Mas é possível realizar isso usando operadores de iteração

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 4):

Não é possível, até porque não faz muito sentido.

O primeiro é possível, mas a sintaxe que está errada, seria assim:

```
for (int a = 0, b = 0; a < 10 && b < 20; a++, b++)
    listaA[a] ...
    listaB[b] ...
```

Mas não fará o que quer. Ele não vai uma do 0 ao 10 e outra do 0 ao 20. Percorrerá as duas do 0 ao 10 e terminará. Se usar o `||` no lugar de `&&`, aí vai fazer o mesmo, quando chegar no décimo primeiro elemento estará pegando algo que não deveria, e provavelmente quebrará a aplicação.

Isto só dá certo se as listas tiverem o mesmo tamanho e quiser percorrer da mesma forma, algo assim:

```
for (int a = 0, b = 0; a < 10 && b < 10; a++, b++)
    listaA[a] ...
    listaB[b] ...
```

Mas na maioria dos casos nem precisaria de duas variáveis, poderia ser só:

```
for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++)
    listaA[a] ...
    listaB[a] ...
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Collections/ForMultiple.java).

No segundo exemplo não tem como fazer, e este é um dos motivos para ter o `for` "simples".

Na verdade raramente precisa percorrer duas listas ao mesmo tempo. Se soubéssemos qual a real necessidade aí poderíamos dar uma solução melhor.

Comment: Se usar o `||` é possível que dê se `listaA[a] ...` for incluído dentro de um bloco `if (a < 10)`.

Comment: @ramaral sim, mas além de complicar um pouco o código, vai torná-lo mais lento. Se precisa mesmo rodar juntos, sem problema, mas se não precisa deve ser mais negócio fazer separado.

Comment: Além que, tendo de usar `if (a < 10)`, bastaria ter uma variável contadora.